# Display stock status on product detail page

Tags: magento2.3, stock, quantity

I have searched a lot and since I am new to magento I would like your help. 
I want to display my stock quantity on my product details page. Can someone please give me a step by step configuration including files to modify?

Answer (score 0):

**From the**

> Admin panel -> Go to -> store -> configuration->  Catalog -> Inventory
>   -> Display Products Availability in Stock on Storefront ->

**Select Yes from the dropdown -> Click on save config button !**

> **Clear the cache and check at frontend - it will not display !**

[Magento 2: Display/Disable Out of Stock Product – Magento 2.3](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-displaydisable-out-of-stock-product-by-your-own/)

[Stock Options](https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-stock-options.html)

Comment: getting or not ??

Comment: If i do as you instructed i cannot display the product quantity on product page just "In stock". I need my clients to be able to see actual product quantity instead of "In stock". Meaning "In stock (qty)".

Comment: use custom theme ?

Comment: Yes i use custom Theme SM Autostore from Magentech.

Comment: wait let me update answer

Comment: if you found solution then post your answer so helpfull for other user

Comment: But this method does not give back "In stock (qty)".

Comment: ok im understand you need to display product qty in detail page right ?

Comment: Yes exactly. i need "In stock" (that is now) to become "In stock qty".

Answer (score 0):

```
for total quantity

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

and if you want to get status

$stockItem = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository');
$productId =1; // YOUR PRODUCT ID
$productStock = $stockItem->get($productId);
$data_p = $productStock->getData();
echo $data_p['is_in_stock']; //1 in stock 0 for out of stock
```

Comment: Can you please instruct me in which file i must edit? Also another thing is not to display negatives. I mean that if stock status in -1 to display 0.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml   or depend on your cutome theme  ==> app/design/frontend/Lucenttheme/Inno/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml    or any in view folder depend on your design and your place. thanks